# Why is each frame presented in my SharpDX Direct2D setup alternating between black and my rendered content?

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx

Sorry this is so long, I wanted to proved enough code as it's hard to explain on it's own

I'm setting up a small test program to make a 2D visual gauge. The structure of the project is that I have a class; 'DirectX11Renderer' which initialises all the SharpDX objects to set up the factories, devices, back buffers, rendertargets, swapchains and layers.

This class then contains drawing methods for drawing basic shapes, filled shapes and text, they can likely be ignored, however the idea of the program is to be able to render the static content of the gauge on one layer (the background, stuff that doesn't really move) and the dynamic content on another layer, so each drawing method has an enum as an argument which specifies the layer to draw on, and then that is passed into this method, which starts drawing on the render target (if not already), pops the last pushed layer (if there was one) and pushes the layer that is required to be drawn on:

```
private void StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(TargetLayer layer, bool draw = true)
        {
            if (draw && !isDrawing)
            {
                d2dRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
                isDrawing = true;
            }

            switch (layer)
            {
                case TargetLayer.Static:
                    if (isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (!isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PushLayer(ref layerParams, staticLayer);
                        isStaticLayerPushed = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TargetLayer.Dynamic:
                    if (isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isStaticLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (!isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PushLayer(ref layerParams, dynamicLayer);
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TargetLayer.None:
                    if (isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isStaticLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (!draw && isDrawing)
            {
                d2dRenderTarget.EndDraw();
                isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
```

So in a class that uses an instance of this DirectX11Renderer class, it starts by setting the background colour without pushing a layer, rendering the static content by clearing the layer then calling several of the draw methods using the static layer as an argument for the enum to push the static layer, then rendering the dynamic content every time a value changes, doing the same thing by using the enum as an argument to pop the static layer and push the dynamic layer, then drawing on it. Finally at the end of the dynamic drawing method I present the frame by using the enum argument of TargetLayer.None to pop all layers, and then present the frame.

What I'm finding is that every time I change the value, (rendering the dynamic content on it's layer, popping the layer then presenting) the screen alternates between showing the content of the dynamic layer on a black background, and all the static and dynamic content as I would want to see it if this were working 100%.

As a minimum working example, here is the code for a form which contains the gauge control:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace SharpDXGauge
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Gauge control;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            control = new Gauge(100, 0);
            control.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            this.Controls.Add(control);
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            control.IndicatorValue = (float)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a minimal example of the gauge class (I've removed most of the rendering):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.DirectWrite;

using DXGI = SharpDX.DXGI; // Direct X Graphics Infrastructure
using D3D = SharpDX.Direct3D;
using D2D1 = SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using D3D11 = SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using DWrite = SharpDX.DirectWrite;

namespace SharpDXGauge
{
    public partial class Gauge : UserControl
    {
        #region Members
        private DirectX11Renderer renderer;

        private float max;
        private float min;
        private float indicatorValue;

        private Point topLeft;
        private Point bottomRight;
        private float height;
        private float width;

        Point valueTextTopLeft;

        Point valueLabelOutlineTopLeft;
        Point valueLabelOutlineBottomRight;

        #endregion

        public Gauge(float max, float min)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            renderer = new DirectX11Renderer(this);

            this.max = max;
            this.min = min;
            this.indicatorValue = min;

            renderer.SetBackgroundColor(renderer.SystemDrawingColorToSharpDXColor(this.BackColor));

            DrawStaticContent();
            DrawDynamicContent();
        }

        #region Drawing

        private void CalculateSizes()
        {
            // Static
            topLeft = new Point() { x = 25, y = 10 };
            bottomRight = new Point() { x = topLeft.x + 20, y = this.Height - 50 };
            height = bottomRight.y - topLeft.y;
            width = bottomRight.x - topLeft.x;

            // Dynamic
            string valueText = indicatorValue.ToString();
            Size2F valueTextSize = renderer.GetTextSize(valueText, 9.75f);

            valueTextTopLeft = new Point() { x = bottomRight.x + 15, y = bottomRight.y - height * indicatorValue / (max - min) - (valueTextSize.Height / 2) };
        }

        private void DrawStaticContent()
        {
            CalculateSizes();
            renderer.ClearLayer(TargetLayer.Static, Color.Transparent);

            renderer.DrawRectangle(TargetLayer.Static, topLeft, bottomRight, Color.Black);

            DrawDynamicContent();

            renderer.PresentFrame();
        }

        private void DrawDynamicContent()
        {
            renderer.ClearLayer(TargetLayer.Dynamic, Color.Transparent);
            CalculateSizes();

            renderer.DrawText(TargetLayer.Dynamic, indicatorValue.ToString(), Color.White, valueTextTopLeft, 9.75f);
            renderer.DrawRoundedRectangle(TargetLayer.Dynamic, valueLabelOutlineTopLeft, valueLabelOutlineBottomRight, 20, Color.Black);

            renderer.PresentFrame();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public float IndicatorValue
        {
            get
            {
                return indicatorValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (indicatorValue != value)
                {
                    indicatorValue = value;
                    DrawDynamicContent();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Disposal

        public new void Dispose()
        {
            renderer.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And my DirectX11Renderer class, I've removed all the unnecessary drawing methods etc:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.DirectWrite;

using DXGI = SharpDX.DXGI; // Direct X Graphics Infrastructure
using D3D = SharpDX.Direct3D;
using D2D1 = SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using D3D11 = SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using DWrite = SharpDX.DirectWrite;
using DMaths = SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;

namespace SharpDXGauge
{
    public enum TargetLayer
    {
        Static,
        Dynamic,
        None
    }

    public struct Point
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
    }

    public partial class DirectX11Renderer : IDisposable
    {
        private Surface backBuffer;
        private D3D11.Device d3dDevice;
        private D3D11.Device1 d3dDevice1;
        private DXGI.Device2 dxgiDevice2;
        private D2D1.Device d2dDevice;
        private SwapChain1 swapChain1;
        private D2D1.Factory d2dFactory;
        private DXGI.Factory2 dxgiFactory2;
        private Adapter dxgiAdapter;
        private RenderTarget d2dRenderTarget;
        private DWrite.Factory dWriteFactory;

        private Layer staticLayer;
        private Layer dynamicLayer;

        SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush;
        //RadialGradientBrush radialGradientBrush;
        //LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush;

        private Color lastBackColour;

        private bool isDrawing;
        private LayerParameters layerParams;
        private bool isStaticLayerPushed;
        private bool isDynamicLayerPushed;

        List<double> renderTimesMsec = new List<double>();

        public DirectX11Renderer(Control surfaceToDrawOn)
        {
            // There seems to be endless ways to set up the different objects required for rendering
            // This is the most efficient I've found that get's everything you need for 2d rendering
            SwapChainDescription1 description = new SwapChainDescription1()
            {
                Width = surfaceToDrawOn.Width,
                Height = surfaceToDrawOn.Height,
                Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                Stereo = false,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Usage = Usage.BackBuffer | Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
                BufferCount = 2,
                Scaling = Scaling.None,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.FlipSequential,
            };

            d3dDevice = new D3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);
            d3dDevice1 = d3dDevice.QueryInterface<D3D11.Device1>();
            dxgiDevice2 = d3dDevice1.QueryInterface<DXGI.Device2>();
            d2dDevice = new D2D1.Device(dxgiDevice2);
            dxgiAdapter = dxgiDevice2.Adapter;

            d2dFactory = new D2D1.Factory(D2D1.FactoryType.SingleThreaded);
            dxgiFactory2 = dxgiAdapter.GetParent<DXGI.Factory2>();
            swapChain1 = new SwapChain1(dxgiFactory2, d3dDevice1, surfaceToDrawOn.Handle, ref description);

            backBuffer = swapChain1.GetBackBuffer<Surface>(0);

            d2dRenderTarget = new RenderTarget(d2dFactory, backBuffer,
                 new RenderTargetProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, D2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
            staticLayer = new Layer(d2dRenderTarget);
            dynamicLayer = new Layer(d2dRenderTarget);

            dWriteFactory = new DWrite.Factory(DWrite.FactoryType.Shared);

            layerParams = new LayerParameters()
            {
                ContentBounds = RectangleF.Infinite,
                Opacity = 1
            };
            solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(d2dRenderTarget, Color.White);
        }

        public void PresentFrame()
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(TargetLayer.None, false);
            swapChain1.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
        }

        public void SetBackgroundColor(Color colour)
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(TargetLayer.None);
            lastBackColour = colour;
            d2dRenderTarget.Clear(colour);
        }

        public void ClearLayer(TargetLayer layer, Color fillColorAfterClear)
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(layer);
            d2dRenderTarget.Clear(fillColorAfterClear);
        }

        public void DrawRectangle(TargetLayer layer, Point topLeft, Point bottomRight, Color colour, float strokeWidth = 1)
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(layer);
            solidColorBrush.Color = colour;
            d2dRenderTarget.DrawRectangle(new DMaths.RawRectangleF(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y), solidColorBrush, strokeWidth);
        }

        public void DrawRoundedRectangle(TargetLayer layer, Point topLeft, Point bottomRight, float roundingRadius, Color colour, float strokeWidth = 1)
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(layer);
            solidColorBrush.Color = colour;
            RoundedRectangle roundedRect = new RoundedRectangle();
            roundedRect.Rect = new DMaths.RawRectangleF(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
            roundedRect.RadiusX = roundingRadius;
            roundedRect.RadiusY = roundingRadius;
            d2dRenderTarget.DrawRoundedRectangle(roundedRect, solidColorBrush, strokeWidth);
        }

        public void DrawText(TargetLayer layer, string text, Color colour, Point topLeft, float fontSize, FontWeight weight = FontWeight.Normal, FontStyle style = FontStyle.Normal,  string font = "Microsoft Sans Serif")
        {
            StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(layer);
            solidColorBrush.Color = colour;
            TextFormat format = new TextFormat(dWriteFactory, font, weight, style, FontStretch.Normal, fontSize);

            Size2F textSize = GetTextSize(text, fontSize, 100, 100);
            Point bottomRight = new Point() { x = topLeft.x + (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Width), y = topLeft.y + (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Height) };

            d2dRenderTarget.DrawText(text, format, 
                new DMaths.RawRectangleF(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y), 
                solidColorBrush);
        }

        public Size2F GetTextSize(string text, float fontSize, float maxWidth = 100000, float maxHeight = 100000, FontWeight weight = FontWeight.Normal, FontStyle style = FontStyle.Normal, string font = "Microsoft Sans Serif")
        {
            TextFormat format = new TextFormat(dWriteFactory, font, weight, style, FontStretch.Normal, fontSize);
            TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(dWriteFactory, text, format, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            return new Size2F(layout.Metrics.Width, layout.Metrics.Height);
        }

        public Color SystemDrawingColorToSharpDXColor(System.Drawing.Color colour)
        {
            Color toRtn = new Color(new byte[4] { colour.R, colour.G, colour.B, colour.A, });
            return toRtn;
        }

        private void StartDrawingAndSwitchLayer(TargetLayer layer, bool draw = true)
        {
            if (draw && !isDrawing)
            {
                d2dRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
                isDrawing = true;
            }

            switch (layer)
            {
                case TargetLayer.Static:
                    if (isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (!isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PushLayer(ref layerParams, staticLayer);
                        isStaticLayerPushed = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TargetLayer.Dynamic:
                    if (isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isStaticLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (!isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PushLayer(ref layerParams, dynamicLayer);
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TargetLayer.None:
                    if (isStaticLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isStaticLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    if (isDynamicLayerPushed)
                    {
                        d2dRenderTarget.PopLayer();
                        isDynamicLayerPushed = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (!draw && isDrawing)
            {
                d2dRenderTarget.EndDraw();
                isDrawing = false;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Release all resources
            backBuffer.Dispose();
            d3dDevice.Dispose();
            d3dDevice1.Dispose();
            dxgiDevice2.Dispose();
            d2dDevice.Dispose();
            swapChain1.Dispose();
            d2dFactory.Dispose();
            dxgiFactory2.Dispose();
            dxgiAdapter.Dispose();
            d2dRenderTarget.Dispose();
            staticLayer.Dispose();
            dynamicLayer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Putting this together gives a minimal example of what I'm seeing, I've removed code handling form resizing so with this, the bottom half appears black to begin with, but using a numerical updown on the form to update the IndicatorValue property creates the alternating all black/ what I want to see frames.

I've been trying to ebug this for a while, I'm beginning to wonder if it's to do with how I've set up my swap chain? At first I thought it must be how I'm handing my layers, and perhaps somehow every other change and dynamic content render it's not popping the layer and only showing the content of the dynamic layer? But stepping through each update has it pushing and popping the layers correctly as far as I can see, and generally not doing it right throws an exception.

Sorry this is so long,

Joe.

Comment: Can you post a compiling project somewhere?

Comment: Heres the full project as a zip on my google drive, let me know if there are any issues!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1B2kqNi3QK7CRnRlRk-JfjfCQRacaxn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code seems very complex to draw a bunch of rectangles and text, I especially suspect your own layer logic. But why in the first place do you use D2D to draw a control in a Winforms app? Seems overkill and Winforms doesn't interop well with GDI+. You could use Winforms (GDI+) only

Comment: It was more the principle of being able to draw static content once and not need to redraw it. It seems a simple enough way to have a common method that starts drawing if not, pops the current layer if it’s not the target layer, then pushes the target layer to draw on, but the way it appears is that the background or static is being set to transparent (hence the black) and the dynamic layer rendering correctly, but I can’t find where my layer logic is going wrong. I’m tempted to try storing the static content as a bitmap, or just render it all in one and not have layers

Comment: Though I may just move back to rendering all over again, or try with a stored bitmap to retrieve for the static content, it just seemed like a way to save some resources, especially if a lot of these were to be used or for frames with more content

Comment: What I meant in my first comment was "Winforms doesn't interop well with DirectX". See airspace issues here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/technology-regions-overview. Direct2D is not suited to own just a portion of the window.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll have a look at other options. In the meantime, I've had a play with it this morning and I think the issue must be my swap chain. I tried a normal swapchain with a single buffer and a Discard swap effect and while there are some scaling issues, it isn't alternating between black and visible frames, so I think there must be something I don't understand about having two buffered frames and the flip sequential swap effect